# why i failed to build mysql using cmake on windows?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, build, cmake, build-process

mysql is a nice piece of code which worth study:)

now i am about to build mysql on windows 7 x64 system using vs 2010.

in fact, i failed to build mysql on windows both using cmake and visual studio ide, the error message is just as follows:

```
90>PostBuildEvent:
90>  CPack: Create package using ZIP
90>  CPack: Install projects
90>  CPack: - Install project: MySQL
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/archive/cmake_install.cmake:3
8 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/archive/RelWithDebInfo/ha_archive.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:57 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/blackhole/cmake_install.cmake
:38 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/blackhole/RelWithDebInfo/ha_blackhole.dll
".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:58 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/example/cmake_install.cmake:3
8 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/example/RelWithDebInfo/ha_example.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:60 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/federated/cmake_install.cmake
:38 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/storage/federated/RelWithDebInfo/ha_federated.dll
".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:61 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/audit_null/cmake_install.cmake
:38 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/audit_null/RelWithDebInfo/adt_null.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:67 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/cmake_install.cmake:38 (F
ILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/RelWithDebInfo/auth.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:68 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/cmake_install.cmake:66 (F
ILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/RelWithDebInfo/auth_test_plugin.dll".

90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:68 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/cmake_install.cmake:94 (F
ILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/RelWithDebInfo/qa_auth_interface.dll"
.
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:68 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/cmake_install.cmake:122 (
FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/RelWithDebInfo/qa_auth_server.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:68 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/cmake_install.cmake:150 (
FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/auth/RelWithDebInfo/qa_auth_client.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:68 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/daemon_example/cmake_install.c
make:38 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/daemon_example/RelWithDebInfo/libdaemon_ex
ample.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:69 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/fulltext/cmake_install.cmake:3
8 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/fulltext/RelWithDebInfo/mypluglib.dll".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:70 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/semisync/cmake_install.cmake:3
8 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/semisync/RelWithDebInfo/semisync_master.dl
l".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:71 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/semisync/cmake_install.cmake:6
6 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/plugin/semisync/RelWithDebInfo/semisync_slave.dll
".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:71 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/sql/cmake_install.cmake:38 (FILE):
90>    file INSTALL cannot find
90>    "D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/sql/RelWithDebInfo/mysqld.exe".
90>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
90>    D:/tmp/mysql-5.5.28/bu/cmake_install.cmake:84 (INCLUDE)
90>
90>
90>EXEC : CPack error : Error when generating package: MySQL
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: 命令“setlocal
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: cd D:\tmp\mysql-5.5.28\bu
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: D:
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: C:\tools\cmake28\bin\cpack.exe -C RelWithDebInfo --confi
g ./CPackConfig.cmake
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDon
e
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
90>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
```

Comment: Seems you are missing a lot of files, or the include path is not set correctly .

Comment: It looks to me like some of the targets in the project did not build so install will fail because its trying to install parts that were not built. I use CMake daily with Visual Studio for years however I have never built mysql with it so its difficult to help further.